# Discard Subsequent Rules Not Working As Intended

Tags: shopping-cart-price-rules

Scenario is I'm running 2 sales this weekend.

1. Sale 1 is 15% Off Sitewide w/ coupon code
2. Sale 2 is BOGO 50% Off Certain Items (These items are living in a
   category which is how it is defining them) No coupon code.

Something is wrong in that right now if the user adds 2 from that category, it is working as intended using the Percent discount: each 2-d rule. However, if a user only wants to buy 1, I still want them to be able to use the 15% off coupon code. I have both enabled to Discard Subsequent Rules.

If I try to use my 15% off coupon right now on just one item, it tells me the coupon is not valid.  It's only doing this on products in that category. If I turn off Disable Subsequent Rules on either cart rule, it works as intended, but then stacks the offers if the user were to buy 2. On my 15% coupon, I don't have any conditions at all set, so it should be taking the 15% off. Is this a bug, or am I missing a setting?

Magento 2.2.6

Comment: Hey there! I'm having exactly the same problem. Did you find a solution?